# NetBeans' toolchain for Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, netbeans, toolchain

has anyone ever written a netbeans' toolchain for MS VC++ compiler? 
Following this [bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=125434).

I read this should be possibile since version 6.7.

I thank in advance you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently writing a module/toolchain to use Visual C++ on Netbeans.
You can find the project called [VCC4N on source forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcc4n/).

It may be a bit late for you, but I hope it can help other people.